# Looping through a json file to find a particular value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

My json file look likes

myjson.json

```
[
{"name":"category_01","data":
[
{"id":"1","word":"ma","given_value":"1"},
{"id":"3","word":"me","given_value":"1"},
] }
[
{"name":"category_02","data":
[
{"id":"1","word":"vea","given_value":"1"},
{"id":"3","word":"ve","given_value":"1"},
] }
```

So what I want here is, check whether a particular value is in this json array using php. Assume that,

myphp.php

```
$word = 've';
```

if this value is in the above array, should find is it in `category_01` or `category_02`. and also want to find `given_value` of matching word.
I just tried in this way,

```
$data = file_get_contents ("myjson.json");
$json = json_decode($data, true);

foreach($arr as $item) { 
$uses = ($item['word']= $word); 
}
```

This doesn't work. How can I fix this, Please help me!

Comment: Check what you're data looks like after you've decoded it. You could use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` for this. I also don't understand why you call your data `$data` when it is still json, and `$json` after you've decoded it from json to a PHP data structure. Swapping those variable names around would make more sense. And where does `$arr` come from?

Comment: @Chathurika the posted json array is in wrong format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the JSON you posted is invalid. I think it should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "category_01",
        "data": [{
                "id": "1",
                "word": "ma",
                "given_value": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "word": "me",
                "given_value": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "category_02",
        "data": [{
                "id": "1",
                "word": "vea",
                "given_value": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "word": "ve",
                "given_value": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Try using on online tool like https://jsonlint.com/ to check your JSON. (if you get errors i recommend build the json again from scratch).

I also recommend checking your json before using it:

```
if ($arr === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    die("incorrect json data");
}
```

To get your value you have to KNOW how your data looks like and then process it:

```
foreach($arr as $category) { 
    foreach($category['data'] as $data) { 
        if(strstr($data['word'], $word))
        echo $category['name'].' '.$data['word'].' '.$data['given_value']."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, very thorough.  Please read the 2nd Note (white box) here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php